# Using SonarQube to Regulate Merging of GitHub Pull Requests

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm working on enabling some code inspection for my team via SonarQube and I have a question not yet answered: is there a way to configure a GitHub project to prevent a pull request merge based on failing SonarQube quality gates? For example, on tripping a critical issue in SonarQube, can the green "Merge Pull Request" button pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPfFq.png) be removed or grayed-out?

I've noticed in the example [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin?preview=/5311422/5636115/PullRequestAnalysis.png), that SonarQube labels itself as having failed in the inspection jobs. That seems to be halfway to the solution that I'm looking for my team. Is there a configuration in SonarQube or GitHub that may enable a "full stop" on the merging of bad code?

I am using Jenkins 2.19.1 as the CI server, with SonarQube Scanner 2.8, and SonarQube server 5.6. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub now supports "[Protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/)".  You can specify a required check and make the SonarQube [GitHub plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) status check required.  If there are critical or blocker issues found, the PR won't be able to be merged as there won't be a merge button.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that's a good start. I started playing with it and indeed, if the job fails, I can't merge the code. However, I'm having difficulty finding how to configure SonarQube to classify the job as failed if a critical or blocker issue is detected. Do you know if that configuration could be set SonarQube server side, or somewhere on the Jenkins server?

Comment: Issues with severity **blocker** or **critical** cause the job to fail.  You configure issue severity on the SonarQube server, for instance via [Quality Profiles](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles)